# Why is Death Proof presented specifically as Thunderbolt for a brief moment?

Tags: title, death-proof

Before *Death Proof*'s real title shows on screen, for a split second the title *Thunderbolt* is shown.

[image]

This is one of the editing techniques used to make the film have the *grindhouse look*. From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Proof):

> Exploitation films were commonly retitled, especially if they received bad press on initial release.

But what is *Thunderbolt*? Is this some reference to another movie or to something within this movie?

Comment: I understand why the 'fake re-title'. I'm asking about the meaning of *Thunderbolt*. My google results just show software and Pokémon. Why this specific title? Edited for clarity.

Comment: Any idea what it says under Thunder Bolt?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 You say "I understand why the 'fake re-title'.", but your question is titled "Why is Death Proof presented as Thunder Bolt for a brief moment?"

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy It's studio and distribution lines, I think.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I've edited the title as well

Comment: @BCdotWEB the question is asking what is the significance of Thunder Bolt, not what is the significance of the fake title - i.e. does the name or phrase "Thunder Bolt" have any in-universe significance in "Death Proof", e.g. is it a character's name, does someone tell a story about a thunderbolt, etc.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy But that wasn't how it was originally presented. Look up the edit history.

Comment: @BCdotWEB The second edit, made ~an hour b4 your comment makes it clear and even the first iteration asks regarding the significance of what the title would mean in the case that it had not been removed: *"What is Thunder Bolt? Is this some reference to another movie or to **something within this movie?"*** Considering the title is over an image from the movie, this rules out that it is a reference to another movie and confirms that it is the previous title and hence, what in-universe meaning does "Thunder Bolt" have in "Death Proof" seems clear to me.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy That first edit was in response to my original comment, and then I still don't see what's bad about my second comment, considering that **the title of this question was incorrect**, and OP has changed it. Also note that the single answer to this question is also based on the question being unclear, especially since his actual question was buried beneath a huge image.

Comment: @BCdotWEB sorry, not trying to suggest any of your comments are "bad" - just that the ambiguity of the title and question were, to me, not an issue, and, given the answer and commentary, hence, my comment to you trying to clarify the focus of the question

Answer (score 1):

It seems that someone, who had originally claim on this title, sued the distributor. That's why it got changed in the last minute.

From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1028528/reviews)

> It also sets out to pastiche the "grindhouse" cinema phenomena, with the original idea of two films being shown as a double feature at drive-in movie theatres from state to state, **with both films often being re-cut and re-edited, not by the filmmakers, but by the theatre owners themselves. This is evident in the amusing switch in title; with the film opening with the caption 'Quentin Tarantino's Thunderbolt', before awkwardly cutting to an obviously out of place title card with 'Death Proof' crudely emblazoned across the screen.**

From [Indiewire](http://www.indiewire.com/2012/12/in-praise-of-death-proof-one-of-quentin-tarantinos-best-movies-128643/)

> Even the title card, jarringly superimposed over the opening credits, looks like a last-minute replacement for an original title (“Thunderbolt”) that was changed by, say, a flighty distributor who got sued by someone who had a prior claim on that name.

Comment: This sounds like just an example of why such retitles happened. E.g., *it may have been due to a distributor who got sued*.